# Prove that if $p\ge 7$ is a prime number , then $p^{4}\equiv 1\pmod{240}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that if $p\ge 7$ is a prime, then $$p^{4}\equiv 1\pmod {240}$$
This is the problem.I found that the given is true with modulo $24$. But I can't find his I cab site that $10\mid p^{4}-1$.

Comment: Prove that $p^4$ is $$\equiv 1\pmod{16},\quad \equiv 1\pmod{3},\quad \equiv 1\pmod{5}$$ and exploit the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: How I proof $$p^{4}\equiv 1\pmod{5}$$.

Comment: By Fermat's little theorem, if $5\nmid n$ we have $n^4\equiv 1\pmod{5}$.

Comment: #Jack D'Aurizio : Please do it in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that $240=16\times3\times5=2^4\times3\times5$.

By Fermat little theorem you have the fact that $p^4\equiv 1 \pmod5$ (because $7\le p)$.

It gives you $\gcd(p^4,5)=1$ and notice that $p\ge 7$. Moreover you know that $\gcd(p^4,3)=1=\gcd(p^4,15)$.

Then you know that $\gcd(p,2)=1$ because $p\ge 7$. Then it gives you, developing by itself $(up+2v=1)$ with Bachet-Bézout, that $\gcd(p^2,2)=1$. You develop again by Bachet-Bézout two times and you have $\gcd(p^4,2)=1$. You do the exact the same thing with $2$, four times, and you get $\gcd(p^4,2^4=16)=1$.

So you conclude that $\gcd(p^4,15\times16=240)=1 \Leftrightarrow p^4\equiv 1 \pmod{240}$.

But you can also use the CRT as @Jack D'Aurizio suggests.